# How to manage images without Asset Cataloge?

Tags: ios, xcode, image, assets, asset-catalog

I need to support different resolutions, so add images with 3 different resolutions. In recent version of Xcode there is Asset Cataloge. But how to do it in old projects where Asset Catalogue does not exist?

[image]

Comment: Add images to the project, load them by specifying full name (including @2x etc.)

Comment: I relasized I can add `Asset Catalogue` afterwards.